# Cygwin Disable Focus-Follows-Mouse

Tags: cygwin, gnu, mouseover

I switch between windows running under Win 10 and windows running under Cygwin. The mouse causes the Cygwin/X windows to gain focus but not the native Windows. This causes problems.

Is it possible to disable the Focus Follows Mouse function in Cygwin?
I am running Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: It is not a programming question so Stackoverflow is not the right place. I do not see any special effect between Cygwin Terminal (Mintty) and other Windows program about the mouse usage.

Comment: MinTTY isn't an X client.

Comment: Does this help with the issue? https://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#window-auto-focus